# Using php's explode function on fractions

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a simple `explode` operation to use array values for inserting records to `mysql` database.

*The code i use is:*

```
// for loop above
$fieldsArr  = explode(',', $field_names);
```

where `$field_names` is a string like :

```
'1_gps_update_coordinates','1' // prints out just fine 

'1_meter_conf_holiday1_end','2099-01-01' // also fine
```

**but**

```
'1_electricity_unit_price','0,100' gives problem.
```

How can I overcome this? Any tip is appricated.

**Ps** `$field_names` values comes directly from database so I cannot really write an `if statement`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you can't change the input data, you can do this:

change the delimiter from comma to semicolon with [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function

```
$field_name = str_replace("','", "';'", $field_name)
```

then you can explode by semicolon

```
$fieldsArr  = explode(';', $field_names);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to insert `float` using english number formatting

```
0.1
```

Instead of european `0,1`

Use `number_formatting()` or simply `str_replace(',', '.', $val);`

Comment: That being said, this also replaces the `,` between strings thus I accepted the other answer.

Comment: @FreshPro that depends on wether you replace it before or after explode. Both answers suggest workarounds and you should consider using a real data abstraction like flushing objects to the database (for example like Doctrine).